# F# computation expression transparent state passing with Bind

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I have the following code that try to read a possibly incomplete data (image data, for example) from a network stream using usual MaybeBuilder:

```
let image = maybe {
    let pos = 2 //Initial position skips 2 bytes of packet ID
    let! width, pos = readStreamAsInt 2 pos
    let! height, pos = readStreamAsInt 2 pos
    let! data, pos = readStream (width*height) pos
    advanceInStream pos
    return {width = width; height = height; pixels = data}
}
```

So, readStream[asInt] [numBytes] [offset] function returns Some [data] or None if data has not arrived yet in a NetworkStream. advanceInStream function is executed when whole network packet is read.

I wonder if there is some way to write some custom computation expression builder to hide pos passing from its user, since it's always the same - I read some data and position in stream and pass it to the next read function as a last parameter.

P.S. MaybeBuilder used:

```
type MaybeBuilder() =    
    member x.Bind(d,f) = Option.bind f d
    member x.Return d = Some d
    member x.ReturnFrom d = d
    member x.Zero() = None
let maybe = new MaybeBuilder()
```

P.P.S

On second thought it seems I *have* to make pos mutable, because of possible "for" or "while" loops in reading. Simple let! works fine with pos Bind shadowing, but you can't hold onto immutability if you add reading in a loop, right? The task becomes trivial then.

Comment: Yes this is indeed possible to write as a computation expression. It's common when defining parser computation expressions (that do need to keep track of the position in the string).

Comment: There are two problems to solve: (1) working with `pos` seems to be a valid job for a `State` computation expression, while (2) working with functions that return `Option<'T>` is a job for `Maybe` comp.expression, exactly as you did. The biggest problem is that **Computation expressions in F# do not combine well**, e.g., you may have one or another, but in order to get two at the same time, you need to write your own custom comp.expression that will do both things. It's fine for learning purposes, but in real-life projects those may appear hard to support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@bytebuster is making good points of maintainability about custom computation expressions but I still thought I demonstrate how to combine the `State` and `Maybe` monad into one.

In "traditional" languages we have good support for composing values such as integers but we run into problems when developing parsers (Producing values from a binary stream is essentially parsing). For parsers we would like to compose simple parser functions into more complex parser functions but here "traditional" languages often lack good support.

In functional languages functions are as ordinary as values and since values can be composed obviously functions can be as well.

First let's define a `StreamReader` function. A `StreamReader` takes a `StreamPosition` (stream + position) and produces an updated `StreamPosition` and a `StreamReaderResult` (the read value or a failure).

```
type StreamReader<'T> = 
  StreamReader of (StreamPosition -> StreamPosition*StreamReaderResult<'T>)
```

(This is the most important step.)

We like to be able to compose simple `StreamReader` functions into more complex ones. A very important property we want to maintain is that the compose operation is "closed" under `StreamReader` meaning that result of composition is a new `StreamReader` which in turn can be composed endlessly.

In order to read an image we need to read the width & height, compute the product and read the bytes. Something like this:

```
let readImage = 
  reader {
    let! width  = readInt32 
    let! height = readInt32 
    let! bytes  = readBytes (width*height)

    return width, height, bytes
  }
```

Because of composition being closed `readImage` is a `StreamReader<int*int*byte[]>`.

In order to be able to compose `StreamReader` like above we need to define a computation expression but before we can do that we need to define the operation `Return` and `Bind` for `StreamReader`. It turns out `Yield` is good to have as well.

```
module StreamReader =
  let Return v : StreamReader<'T> =
    StreamReader <| fun sp -> 
      sp, (Success v)

  let Bind (StreamReader t) (fu : 'T -> StreamReader<'U>) : StreamReader<'U> =
    StreamReader <| fun sp -> 
      let tsp, tr = t sp
      match tr with
      | Success tv ->
        let (StreamReader u) = fu tv
        u tsp
      | Failure tfs -> tsp, Failure tfs

  let Yield (ft : unit -> StreamReader<'T>) : StreamReader<'T> =
    StreamReader <| fun sp -> 
      let (StreamReader t) = ft ()
      t sp
```

`Return` is trivial as the `StreamReader` should return the given value and don't update the `StreamPosition`.

`Bind` is a bit more challenging but describes how to compose two `StreamReader` functions into a new one. `Bind` runs the first `StreamReader` function and checks the result, if it's a failure it returns a failure otherwise it uses the `StreamReader` result to compute the second `StreamReader` and runs that on the update stream position.

`Yield` just creates the `StreamReader` function and runs it. `Yield` is used by F# when building computation expressions.

Finally let's create the computation expression builder

```
type StreamReaderBuilder() =
  member x.Return v   = StreamReader.Return v
  member x.Bind(t,fu) = StreamReader.Bind t fu
  member x.Yield(ft)  = StreamReader.Yield ft

let reader = StreamReaderBuilder ()
```

Now we built the basic framework for combining `StreamReader` functions. In addition we would we need to define the primitive `StreamReader` functions.

Full example:

```
open System
open System.IO

// The result of a stream reader operation is either
//  Success of value
//  Failure of list of failures
type StreamReaderResult<'T> =
  | Success of 'T
  | Failure of (string*StreamPosition) list

and StreamPosition =
  {
    Stream    : byte[]
    Position  : int
  }

  member x.Remaining = max 0 (x.Stream.Length - x.Position)

  member x.ReadBytes (size : int) : StreamPosition*StreamReaderResult<byte[]> =
    if x.Remaining < size then
      x, Failure ["EOS", x]
    else
      let nsp = StreamPosition.New x.Stream (x.Position + size)
      nsp, Success (x.Stream.[x.Position..(x.Position + size - 1)])

  member x.Read (converter : byte[]*int -> 'T) : StreamPosition*StreamReaderResult<'T> =
    let size = sizeof<'T>
    if x.Remaining < size then
      x, Failure ["EOS", x]
    else
      let nsp = StreamPosition.New x.Stream (x.Position + size)
      nsp, Success (converter (x.Stream, x.Position))

  static member New s p = {Stream = s; Position = p;}

// Defining the StreamReader<'T> function is the most important decision
//   In this case a stream reader is a function that takes a StreamPosition 
//   and produces a (potentially) new StreamPosition and a StreamReadeResult
type StreamReader<'T> = StreamReader of (StreamPosition -> StreamPosition*StreamReaderResult<'T>)

// Defining the StreamReader CE
module StreamReader =
  let Return v : StreamReader<'T> =
    StreamReader <| fun sp -> 
      sp, (Success v)

  let Bind (StreamReader t) (fu : 'T -> StreamReader<'U>) : StreamReader<'U> =
    StreamReader <| fun sp -> 
      let tsp, tr = t sp
      match tr with
      | Success tv ->
        let (StreamReader u) = fu tv
        u tsp
      | Failure tfs -> tsp, Failure tfs

  let Yield (ft : unit -> StreamReader<'T>) : StreamReader<'T> =
    StreamReader <| fun sp -> 
      let (StreamReader t) = ft ()
      t sp

type StreamReaderBuilder() =
  member x.Return v   = StreamReader.Return v
  member x.Bind(t,fu) = StreamReader.Bind t fu
  member x.Yield(ft)  = StreamReader.Yield ft

let reader = StreamReaderBuilder ()

let read (StreamReader sr) (bytes : byte[]) (pos : int) : StreamReaderResult<'T> =
  let sp    = StreamPosition.New bytes pos
  let _, sr = sr sp
  sr

// Defining various stream reader functions
let readValue (converter : byte[]*int -> 'T) : StreamReader<'T> =
  StreamReader <| fun sp -> sp.Read converter

let readInt32 = readValue BitConverter.ToInt32
let readInt16 = readValue BitConverter.ToInt16
let readBytes size : StreamReader<byte[]> = 
  StreamReader <| fun sp -> 
    sp.ReadBytes size

let readImage = 
  reader {
    let! width  = readInt32 
    let! height = readInt32 
    let! bytes  = readBytes (width*height)

    return width, height, bytes
  }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  // Sample byte stream
  let bytes   = [|2;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;1;2;3;4;5;6|] |> Array.map byte
  let result  = read readImage bytes 0

  printfn "%A" result

  0
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I understood the main idea - the monadic type itself is not a value, but a function state -> state * result, so Bind  (and whole expression too) returns this function which allows passing stream position down the chain. And seems I'm wrong with "For" loops and mutability in my post, I'll try to write it properly now.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Composing parser functions is very powerful. If you peek at for instance `FParsec` (a parser library) you see that it uses a similar approach.

Comment: Added a bit more clarification.